# Combined probability function

Tags: numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have two PDFs given by:

```
fS1[x_?NumericQ] := PDF[NormalDistribution[1, 0.05], x];
FS1[x_?NumericQ] := CDF[NormalDistribution[1, 0.05], x];

fS2[x_?NumericQ] := 
  PDF[GumbelDistribution[1 - EulerGamma*0.25*6^0.5/Pi, 0.25*6^0.5/Pi],
    x];
FS2[x_?NumericQ] := 
  CDF[GumbelDistribution[1 - EulerGamma*0.25*6^0.5/Pi, 0.25*6^0.5/Pi],
    x];
```

And I want to compute the combined CDF:

```
FS12[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[fS1[y]*FS2[x - y], {y, -Infinity, +Infinity}]
NIntegrate[FS12[x], {x, -Infinity, +Infinity}]
```

But the output I get is:

```
 NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand FS[x] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.,3.67005*10^28}}.
```

So I'm still struggling with FS12. Any additional ideas?

Comment: You'll need to change all of the instances of `[x]=` to `[x_]:=` and `Integrate` to `NIntegrate`.

Comment: `FS12` appears to be a CDF rather than a PDF.

Comment: @JimB Thank you! I also used `?NumericQ` but I still get an error...

Comment: Quick experiment. Instead of your last `NIntegrate` do this `Table[Print[{z,FS12[z]}],{z,-100,-50,5}];` and see what you get. Then think about why you would get that.

Comment: @Bill you are correct! When I constrained the ranges of integration the problem was solved! Thank you!!